# I have installed CakePHP and some folders are missing

Tags: cakephp, directory-structure, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-3.x

I just installed CakePHP on my windows machine using `composer`.

My folders after installation:

```
bin
config
logs
plugins
src
tests
tmp
vendor
webroot
```

I then checked out the "blog tutorial" on CakePHP Cookbook and noticed that I don't have the folders called `app` or `lib`.

Where did they go? Or did I just do something wrong during the installation?

Comment: Make sure you are following [CakePHP 3.x Blog Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html), and not 2.x

Comment: i guess that's what happens when you don't read carefull enough >.<

Comment: @InigoFlores Can you add that as the answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are mixing CakePHP versions.

This is CakePHP 2.x folder structure:

```
/path_to_document_root
    /app
    /lib
    /plugins
    /vendors
```

And this is CakePHP 3.x:

```
/cake_install
    /bin
    /config
    /logs
    /plugins
    /src
    /tests
    /tmp
    /vendor
    /webroot
```

Make sure you are following [CakePHP 3.x Blog Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html), and not CakePHP 2.x.